# Xamarin.Forms: Unable to deserialise/receive JSON data from Firebase realitime database

Tags: c#, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

This is my first stack-overflow questions so I am sorry if this is formatted wrong. I have been trying to use Xamarin.Forms in conjunction with a firebase realtime database but am unable to correctly receive the data. I keep getting the following Exception.

(I can't figure out how to link a local image, so here is the exception message):

```
Unhandled Exception:

Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: Exception occured while processing the request.

Url: https://MY_DATABASE_LINK/users/user_name1/.json
Request Data: 
Response: {"age":"Age_Val1","fName":"First_Val1","lName":"Last_Val1"}
```

I am using Xamarin with the NuGet package FirebaseDatabase.net and have been trying to follow the following tutorials and online questions:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80017/firebase-database-query

I have tried using both techniques and the same exception is thrown. It seems the database is sending me back the right data formatted as JSON but my code is unable to deserialise it. Here is my JSON database structure, and the code I am attempting to run -

```
FirebaseHelper.cs:

    public class FirebaseHelper
    {
        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://MY_DATABASE_LINK.firebaseio.com/");

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
        {

            return (await firebase
              .Child("users")
              .Child("user_name1")
              .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
              {
                  FName = item.Object.FName,
                  LName = item.Object.LName,
                  Age = item.Object.Age
              }).ToList();
            }

    }
```

```
Person.cs:

public class Person
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

```
JSON Database Structure:

{
  "users" : {
    "user_name1" : {
      "age" : "Age_Val1",
      "fName" : "First_Val1",
      "lName" : "Last_Val1"
    },
    "user_name2" : {
      "age" : "Age_Val2",
      "fName" : "First_Val2",
      "lName" : "Last_Val2"
    },
    "user_name3" : {
      "age" : "Age_Val3",
      "fName" : "First_Val3",
      "lName" : "Last_Val3"
    }
  }
}
```

```
Alt code tested:

List<Person> list_users = new List<Person>();
string[] ss = new string[] { "it", "succeeded" };
var items = await firebase
     .Child("users")
     .OrderByKey()
     .OnceAsync<Person>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
     Person user = new Person
         {
             FName = item.Object.FName,
             LName = item.Object.LName,
             Age = item.Object.Age
         };
     list_users.Add(user);
}

return list_users;
```

I expected that the async void would retrieve all the objects/data from the JSON object 'user_name1' and assign them each to the variables in 'Person.cs', and then create a single length list of the first user.

I also did this with just the Child("users") and it returned a larger JSON object but still threw an exception (would have expected a list of users with length 3)

I am just wondering why this exception is being thrown? Or if I am trying to read and assign the data incorrectly, and if so, how should I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stackoverflow! Don't worry, your question is perfectly formatted and pretty well setted. I'm not a firebase expert, but with exception message _"Exception occured while processing the request."_ and _"Url: https://MY_DATABASE_LINK/users/user_name1/.json"_ (specifically _"/.json"_ part) I can tell that you requesting your data in a wrong way/sequence.

Comment: How are you calling this method in you viewmodel? Can you debug it using breakpoints and then see what are you getting?

Comment: Hi Wasif, I have used breakpoints and it has not given me much more information. As it is in one big block it executes and fails in that block. It seems that it never calls my model Person function as it never showed a breakpoint in the Person class.

Answer (score 0):

From your `Person.cs`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then `FirebaseHelper.cs` at least should be like this:

```
public class FirebaseHelper
   {
        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://MY_DATABASE_LINK.firebaseio.com/");

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
        {

            return (await firebase
              .Child("<table_name>") // should only be your table name,here should be 'users'
              .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
              {
                  FName = item.Object.FName,
                  LName = item.Object.LName,
                  Age = item.Object.Age
              }).ToList();
            }
}
```

Finally , get persons as follow:

```
FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper(); 
var allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAllPersons();
```

If other problem , you can show firebase database's table_name screenshot.